# Remove any number into a string in PHP

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm trying to remove the numbers into the element id using this code, because in my code I would like to remove the strings that contains id="###":

```
for($cont = 0;$cont<3000;$cont++)
{
    $strcont = 'id="'.$cont.'"';
    $pro[0]=str_replace($strcont,'',$pro[0]);
}
```

But I think I can do this easy and I don't know why. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove that loop and use just:

```
$pro[0] = preg_replace('#id="([0-9]+)"#i', '', $pro[0]);
```

`i` modifier could be useful if `id` property is not always in lowercase.